# Save canvas as image PaperJS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, paperjs

I have created a canvas with image and few shapes over the image. Now i need to save the whole canvas as image when i click save button. how can i do it. can any one help me.

I did as you said but its not working here is my code. can you check whether i included everything.

```
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
```

Javascript file i have included is

```
<script src="lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/paper.js"></script>
```

And here is the code:

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".save").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "savepic.php",
                data: {image: dataURL}
            }).done(function(respond){
                console.log(respond);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Save canvas to an image URL and upload it to a PHP server**

You can save your canvas to an image URL like this (default is .png format):

```
canvas.toDataURL();
```

Here's how to get that dataURL posted on the server.

Client Side:

```
// create a dataUrl from the canvas
var dataURL= canvas.toDataURL();

// use jQuery to POST the dataUrl to you php server
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "upload.php",
    data: {image: dataURL}
}).done(function( respond ) {
    // Done...report success or failure
    // You will get back the temp file name
    // or "Unable to save this image."
    console.log(respond);
});
```

Server File: upload.php

```
<?php

// make sure the image-data exists and is not empty
// xampp is particularly sensitive to empty image-data 
if ( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"]) ) {    

    // get the dataURL
    $dataURL = $_POST["image"];  

    // the dataURL has a prefix (mimetype+datatype) 
    // that we don't want, so strip that prefix off
    $parts = explode(',', $dataURL);  
    $data = $parts[1];  

    // Decode base64 data, resulting in an image
    $data = base64_decode($data);  

    // create a temporary unique file name
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    // write the file to the upload directory
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

    // return the temp file name (success)
    // or return an error message just to frustrate the user (kidding!)
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save this image.';

}
```

Some usual gotchas (note that xampp is particularly sensitive to these gotchas):

- Make sure the dataURL is not empty (you might even check this client-side -- not shown).
- Make sure you have enabled file uploading on the server.
- Make sure you have defined adequate file upload size limit on the server.
- Make sure you have properly defined your upload directory.
- Make sure you have permissions set properly on the upload directory.

...And, be patient.  You might have to tinker with the server to get running.

Comment: @markE.. When i click save it should save in server not in local system. When i google it few said to send with post. How can i send this in post method whether it will act as image. Can u post a sample here.

Comment: Sure, what web server are you using?

Comment: Windows Xampp - Apache web server

Comment: See my edited answer for client+server code to post and save your canvas as an image on your php server.

Comment: @markE.. I did something wrong its not working i edited above can you please check it.

Comment: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toDataURL' of null** This is what i am getting